# RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request for ReasteasyClient

Tags: java, multithreading, client, resteasy

I create a Spring bean for making rest call. This bean is a singleton.

```
@Component
public class MyClient {

     private transient ResteasyClientBuilder builder;

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
         builder = (ResteasyClientBuilder) ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
         builder.establishConnectionTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         builder.socketTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     }

     public void makeHttpCall(String url){
         ResteasyClient client = builder.build();
         ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url);
         Builder invocationBuilder = target.request();
         Response response = invocationBuilder.post(...);
     }
}
```

MyClient creates a new ResteasyClient for each request. This client works well most of the time, but occasionally it throws `RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request` Exception. Can anyone give me some hints on why this is happening and how to solve it? Many thanks!

I know the Client should be reused, but in my case, I only reuse the builder so that I don't need to worry about multiple threads accessing the same client for now.

If multiple threads access the the same client at the same time, I will have **Unable to invoke** Exception. However in this case, a new client is created for each request.

Comment: What's class in your case you are implementing as singleton? I didn't quite understand you.